# Show limit function (a.e) of bounded functions in $\mathcal{L}^1$ is bounded

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f_n : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence that is bounded in $\mathcal{L}^1$ meaning there exists $M > 0$ such that

$$\int_S |f_n| d\mu \leq M \quad \forall n.$$

Suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. where $f : S \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable. Prove that

$$\int_S |f| d\mu \leq M.$$

---

**My try**

- Step one (because $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e.)

$$\int_S f d\mu = \int_S \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n d\mu$$

- Step two: (we use the Fatou's lemma to obtain):

$$
\int_S |f| d\mu 
=
\int_S \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n| d\mu
= \int_S \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n| d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_S |f_n| d\mu \leq M,
$$

where the first inequality follows from Fatou's lemma and the second inequality follows from the fact that $f_n$ is bounded in $\mathcal{L}^1$.

Therefore, we have shown that $\int_S |f| d\mu \leq M$, as required.

---

**Questions**

1. Using $\int_S f d\mu = \int_S \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n d\mu$, can I write $\int_S |f| d\mu = \int_S \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n| d\mu$? In other words, am I using the property of a.e. correctly?
2. Is there any other way than Fatou's lemma to show this?

Comment: @coudy: Yes. I am using it in my proof.

Comment: Indeed, my mystake. Your proof is fine and if $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ then $|f_n(x)| \rightarrow |f(x)|$ so that a.e. convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ implies a.e. convergence of $|f_n|$ to $|f|$.

Comment: @coudy: Can you please let me know how you would show $f_n \to f$ a.e. then $|f_n| \to |f|$ almost everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that if $f_n$ converges a.e. to $f$ then $|f_n|$ converges a.e. to $|f|$.

Indeed, if $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ then $|f_n(x)| \rightarrow |f(x)|$.
So we have the inclusion
$$\{x \in S \mid f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)\} \subset \{x \in S \mid |f_n(x)| \rightarrow |f(x)|\}.
$$
If the first set is of complement of zero measure, so is the second one.

There may be other ways to prove your statement, but Fatou's lemma gives a quick short proof that seems hard to beat.